# Trying to mock Store getLocale, getting "Method cannot be configured..."

Tags: magento2.2.3, unit-tests

I have this Magento 2 unit test code:

```
    $storeInterfaceMockDe = $this->getMockBuilder(\Magento\Store\Model\Store::class)
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->setMethods(['getLocaleCode'])
        ->getMock();
    $storeInterfaceMockDe->expects($this->any())->method('getLocalCode')->willReturn('de_DE');
```

But PHPUnit throws:

> Trying to configure method "getLocalCode" which cannot be configured 
>   because it does not exist, has not been specified, is final, or is
>   static

[But the core uses similar code](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Store/Test/Unit/Block/Store/SwitcherTest.php#L110).

What am I doing wrong?

Actually the method is a magic method, so it really does not exist -- but why does it work in the core code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo in the method name. The mocked method is `getLocaleCode` (with an `e` in Locale), and the expectation is set for a method `getLocalCode` (without the `e`).

**Small side note**, somewhat unrelated to your question:
I don't like partial mocks, so I generally also add the existing methods to the mock if I have to configure magic methods via the builder:

```
->setMethods(array_merge(get_class_methods(Store::class), ['getLocaleCode']))
```

Comment: Cool, thanks also for the unrelated side note. It's quite related though.